# Networkx Shortest Path nodes movement

Tags: python, networking, networkx, simpy

How can I make a function in Python that allows of the movement of the packets from source to target using the shortest path?

The `shortest_path()` function just returns the names of the nodes. How can I make the packet move through that particular path?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about maximum flow in your graph from `start` to `finish`? If so, there are [bunch of methods for working with flows](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.flow.html) in `NetworkX`.

For example, [`maximum_flow(G, s, t, capacity='capacity', flow_func=None, **kwargs)`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.maximum_flow). It accepts your graph and start and finish nodes in it.

It returns:

> - `flow_value` (*integer, float*) – Value of the maximum flow, i.e., net outflow from the source.
> - `flow_dict` (*dict*) – A dictionary containing the value of the flow that went through each edge.

So your code will be like:

```
flow_value, flow_dict = nx.maximum_flow(G, 'x', 'y')
```

Now in dictionary you can find all the edges in the flow and their usage.